# Python error when using qgis2web

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I have some layers that i want to publish after creating html / open layers format web maps using leaflets. Every time i try, i get this error. in fact i am unable to use pluggins. Please suggest. Error as below:

I am new on this stack exchange and i could not figure out where to post my next question to Mr Evan. I am an Architect and an Urban Planner by profession. I use QGIS for urban planning projects with government of Jharkhand, Inida. basically i dont understand python scripts.... Is there a way to fix my problem so that i can use qgis2web for publishing maps on our government website please?

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 58, in run
    self.dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)
  File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 149, in __init__
    self.autoUpdatePreview()
  File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 310, in autoUpdatePreview
    (auto_preview, message) = self.shouldAutoPreview()
  File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 294, in shouldAutoPreview
    if total_features > int(self.previewFeatureLimit.text()):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.20 Las Palmas, e8e15d5b1e 

Python Path:
C:\Users\HP\.qgis2\python\plugins\GeoCoding\libs
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/HP/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\HP\.qgis2\python\plugins
C:\Users\HP\.qgis2\python\plugins
C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis_resource_sharing
C:\Users\HP\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis_resource_sharing
C:\Users\HP\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis_resource_sharing\ext_libs
.
C:\Users\HP\.qgis2\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools
E:/GISmp/NF Infratech/Final_Amrut_Formulation_20180402/Saraikela/udhdcheck
```

Comment: I am new on this stack exchange and i could not figure out where to post my next question to Mr Evan. I am an Architect and an Urban Planner by profession. I use QGIS for urban planning projects with government of Jharkhand, Inida. basically i dont understand python scripts.... Is there a way to fix my problem so that i can use qgis2web for publishing maps on our government website please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS, open the Python console by pressing CTRL + ALT + P - it should appear below your map. Type the following into the Python console (or ideally, copy and paste it), and press Enter:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
```

The copy and paste the following code into the Python console and press Enter:

```
QSettings().setValue("qgis2web/previewFeatureLimit", "1000")
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Tom, I followed the steps and now the pluggin opens. this time there is a new problem and that is the circular wait sign is continuously playing and the Error is as below

Comment: Error

qgis2web produced an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 318, in previewMap
preview_file = self.createPreview()
File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 280, in createPreview
dest_folder=utils.tempFolder()).index_file
File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 89, in write
folder=dest_folder)
File "C:/Users/HP/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 112, in writeOL ......more that cant fit

Comment: I'll need the whole error, I'm afraid. Can you edit your question, and paste it at the end (make that clear in the question). Thanks!

Comment: May i please have your email address? I would like to send you print screen. Now the error has gone, but it only publishes one layer out of 3 layers. I have an urban land use layer, roads and point layer. i only see point layers in html format.

Comment: Please visit https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/. You log this as an issue there, and upload a screenshot.